# TSQL Select element with only one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a project in which I need to save request for file. I have to save the state of the request with the date of each step.

I have two tables in my database :

FileRequest :

[image]

FileRequestStatus :

[image]

I would like to create a request to get each FileName from the table `FileRequest` having only the `Status == 'NEW'`. The desired output would be in this case `C12345, LIVE`.

If you have a better idea in order to build my database, I'll take it

I tried something like that :

```
SELECT [FileName] FROM [FileRequest]
INNER JOIN [FileRequestStatus] ON [FileRequestStatus].[RequestId] = [FileRequest].[RequestId]
GROUP BY [FileRequestStatus].[RequestId]
HAVING COUNT([FileRequestStatus].[RequestStatus]) < 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FR.FileName 
FROM [FileRequest] FR
INNER JOIN [FileRequestStatus] FRS ON FRS.[RequestId] = FR.[RequestId]
GROUP BY FR.FileName 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN FRS.RequestStatus <> 'New' THEN 1 END) = 0 --No statuses other than `NEW`
AND COUNT(CASE WHEN FRS.RequestStatus = 'New' THEN 1 END) >= 1 --Atleast one status `NEW`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest method is aggregation:

```
select fr.FileName
from nep.FileRequest fr join
     nep.FileRequestStatus] frs
     on frs.RequestId = fr.RequestId
group by fr.FileName
having min(frs.RequestStatus) = max(frs.RequestStatus) and
       min(frs.RequestStatus) = 'New';
```

Note:  This assumes that the request status is never `NULL` (although that is easy to take into account).

What this does is aggregate by file name and then check that the statuses for a given file are all equal (the first condition) and equal to `'New'` (the second condition).

Comment: Hi, I used the sentence from vkp `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN FRS.RequestStatus <> 'New' THEN 1 END) = 0`. Is it better than yours : `having min(frs.RequestStatus) = max(frs.RequestStatus)` ?

Comment: @XavierW. . . . It seems more complicated to me, but that really is just a personal opinion.

Comment: I'm sorry to insist but I really don't understand the logic of the following line : `having min(frs.RequestStatus) = max(frs.RequestStatus)`. Could you please give me an explanation ? What happend if there is no line with only one status ? `min(frs.RequestStatus)` would have a value of `2` ?!

Comment: @XavierW. . . . That condition checks that the minimum and maximum values are the same.  Or, more simply, that all the values are equal (or null).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `[FileName]` to your `GROUP BY`, then you can select it in result

```
SELECT [nep].[FileRequest].[FileName] FROM [nep].[FileRequest]
INNER JOIN [nep].[FileRequestStatus] ON [nep].[FileRequestStatus].[RequestId] = [nep].[FileRequest].[RequestId]
GROUP BY [nep].[FileRequestStatus].[RequestId], [nep].[FileRequest].[FileName]
HAVING COUNT([nep].[FileRequestStatus].[RequestStatus]) < 2
```